# Iterate through JUnit Test Case with Array and Constant Value

Tags: java, junit

I would like to create a JUnit Test Case that creates a case for every iteration of an array. How do I go about doing this? I've seen some docs about `@Parameterized.Parameters` but it seems like I will need to reconstruct my original array to look like `{{array[0], constantValue}, {array[1], constantValue}}`. Is there any way I can get JUnit to do the following:

```
public class Testing {

String[] array;
String constantValue;

@Test
public void test_arrayValue0() {
   assertEquals(array[0] + " is true", true, method(array[0], constantValue));
}

@Test
public void test_arrayValue1() {
   assertEquals(array[1] + "is true", true, method(array[1], constantValue));
}


@Test
public void test_arrayValue2() {
   assertEquals(array[2] + " is true", true, method(array[2], constantValue));
}
//..until array is complete
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parameterize your test with the array values (and optionally indices):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Testing {
    private final static String constantValue = "myConstant";

    @Parameters
    public static Object[][] params() { 
         return new Object[][]{ 
                new Object[] { "item0", 0 },
                new Object[] { "item1", 1 },
                //...
         };
    }

    @Param(0)
    public String arrayValue;

    @Param(1)
    public int arrayIndex;

    @Test
    public void test_arrayValue() {
        assertEquals("array" + arrayIndex + " is true", true, method(arrayValue, constantValue));
    }
}
```

Then your test_arrayValue will be called as many times as you supplied parameters, each time with your next pair of index and value you specified.

Alternatively, you can define you array just a field:

```
private final String[] array = new String[] {"item0", "item1", ... }
```

And then parameterize your test with an index only.